# Mockito Not Able to Mock function call present in target class's constructor

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

I am trying to test the following class using Mockito and JUnit :

```
public class A {
   private SomeClass someObject;
   private SomeImpClass someImpObject1;
   private SomeImpClass2 someImpObject2;

   public A(SomeImpClass someImpObject1, SomeImpClass2 someImpObject2){
       someObject = makeNewObject(someImpObject1, someImpObject2);
   }

   public makeNewObject(SomeImpClass1 someImpObject1, SomeImpClass2 someImpObject2){
       return new SomeObject(someImpObject1,someImpObject2);
   }

  public usingSomeObject(){
      someObject.doSomething();
  }
 }
```

So, I wrote a Unit Test using Mockito and JUnit :

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {
  @Mock
  SomeImpClass1 someImpObject1;

  @Mock
  SomeImpClass2 someImpObject2;

  @Mock
  SomeObject someObject;

  @Spy
  A a;

 @Before
public void setUp() {
    when(A.makeNewObject).thenReturn(someObject);
    this.A = new A(this.someImpObject1, someImpObject2);
    when(someObject.doSomething).thenReturn(something);
}
}
```

The Issue I am facing here is, although I have stubbed the function makeNewObject to return a Mocked object of SomeClass, the code flow is still going inside the fucntion (makeNewObject) and giving a null exception.

What Am I Doing Wrong ?
I have wasted a day behind this.

Not Very Fluent with Mockito.

Comment: what is this ` when(A.makeNewObject).thenReturn(someObject);` A is a class and makeNewObject is not a variable. put proper code

Comment: Your test class here doesn't even compile.  Perhaps you could show the actual code you're having trouble with?  Possibly you're reassigning `a` after you stubbed `a.makeNewObject()`, so that `a` is then referring to something that hasn't been stubbed.  It's no good stubbing one object, then using an entirely different object in your test.

Comment: Please provide code that actually demonstrates your issue. I tried to replace `A` with the object `a`, but that delivers a MockitoExcpetion: Cannot instantiate a @Spy for 'a' field (no default constructor).

Comment: This wasnt an actual code, it was more of a representation, and my apologies @pvpkiran, it is a.makeNewObject()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wont be able to achieve what you are aiming for with spying and stubbing.
This is because your aiming at stubbing a method used in a constructor.. but you cannot start stubbing once you created a concrete object and spy it.. can't be done..

I would suggest creating a private class inside the test class which extends your class under test, override the method invoked in the constructor and then use it in your tests:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ATest {

  @Mock
  SomeObject someObjectMock;

  A a;

 @Before
 public void setUp() {
    this.a = new MyTest();
 }

 private class MyTest extends ATest{

     @Override
     public makeNewObject(SomeImpClass1 someImpObject1, SomeImpClass2 someImpObject2){
   return someObjectMock;
 }

}
```

Now you dont need to use spying and stubbing of it also as the overriden method is always returning what you expect in the test.

Comment: Worked for me.
Thanks Much. :)

Comment: No problem. glad it did

Comment: @Maciej Kowalski Should it not be `private class MyTest extends A{` ? 
`